# Elixir tranform data from one List with lists

Tags: erlang, elixir

Can your help me with this questions, please

1 - My questions is How does transform the data from one List with lists.

For Example:

In this list transform "Elixir" to --> :Elixir,  the number string to integer

```
[
    ["Language", "Elixir"],
    ["Language", "Python"],
    ["Language", "Rust"],
    ["Framework", "Phoenix", "1"]
]
```

2 - My second questions is which is more convenient, handle this as a list or maps.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting nested lists might be done in many ways; here the most appropriate one would be to use pattern matching in mapper’s clauses.

```rb
input = [
    ["Language", "Elixir"],
    ["Language", "Python"],
    ["Language", "Rust"],
    ["Framework", "Phoenix", "1"]
]

Enum.map(input, fn
  [kind, name] ->
    [kind, String.to_atom(name)]
  [kind, name, ver] ->
    [kind, String.to_atom(name), String.to_integer(ver)]
end)
#⇒ [
#   ["Language", Elixir],
#   ["Language", :Python],
#   ["Language", :Rust],
#   ["Framework", :Phoenix, 1]
# ]
```

Using a map would be way more convenient because you might handle the update wisely whether the key is presented or not.